# Registration form [FOSUserBundle]

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I built my own registration form and when I try to register users it doesn't react. Everything with FOSUserBundle works good. Also when I use the default FOSUserBundle registration form it works and it saves all the data in my table. Should I use only the default form from FOSUserBundle or what?

Here is my form that I made:

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="surname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="email"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: please be more precise when asking a question ... it doesn't react can hardly be anything ... you can't submit the form, it times out, it does not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the registration form from the controller ( if you are overriding the controller ) to the view in order to have the csrf token available. Otherwise the form will not validate.

In order to overwrite FOSUserBundle's standard registration form use [bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

Please read FOSUserBundle's documentation chapter [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md).

If you just want to add "name" and "surname" to your user entity, add the properties and the mapping information and afterwards add the fields to the overriden form class. then override the registration form template provided by FOSUserBundle if you need further  changes in there.

Comment: so what i think is wrong, so i must use only the form from the controller?

Comment: you can override the default form or override the whole registration controller that's your choice. but if you just want to add "name" and "surname" to your user entity you only have to override the form and the template and add the properties+mapping information to your user entity.

Answer (score 0):

Read [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) how you can override registration controller if you need extend functionality. Or you can just [override](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) standard form to add additional fields.